# opencv c++ code error while applying some function to video file

Tags: c++, opencv, qt-creator

I get this error while trying to run OpenCV C++ code using qtcreator and the code used to 
add some features to video file

`opencv error :assertion failed <fixed type<> ::<<Mat*>obj>->type<>==m type> in create file c:\opencv\sources\mogules\core\src\matrix.cpp`

I tried to add file `dWidth` and `dHeight` but it did not work.

```
int main(){
    Mat frame;
    Mat image;
    VideoCapture cap("file source");
    namedWindow("window",1);
    while(1){
        cap>>frame;
        GpyrTempIIR g;
        g.processOnFrame(frame,image); //this is the process i do on frame 
        imshow("window",image);
        waitKey(33);
    }
}
  void GpyrTempIIR::processOnFrame(const Mat& src, Mat& out) {
    src.convertTo(src,CV_32F); //Convert to Float
    resize(srcFloat,blurred,blurredsize,0,0,CV_INTER_AREA);
    /* Method in openCv to resize a video
     * INTER_AREA is a fast method that gets the average of several pixels, which
     is good for shrinking an image but not so good for enlarging an image. */
    if(first){
        first=false;
        blurred.copyTo(LowPassHigh);    // Using Storing Method
        blurred.copyTo(LowPassLow);
        src.copyTo(out);
    } else {
        //apply Temporal filter substraction of two IIR LowPass Filters
        LowPassHigh = LowPassHigh * (1-fHigh) + fHigh * blurred;
        LowPassLow = LowPassLow * (1-fLow) + fLow * blurred;
        blurred = LowPassHigh - LowPassLow;

        blurred*=alpha; // amplify , multuplying by alpha value


       resize(blurred, outFloat, src.size(), 0, 0, CV_INTER_LINEAR);   // resize back                         
           outFloat += srcFloat;      // add back to original frame
         outFloat.convertTo(out, CV_8U);         // convert to 8 bit
    }
}
```

Comment: int main(){
Mat frame;
Mat image;
VideoCapture cap("file source");

namedWindow("window",1);
while(1){
cap>>frame;
GpyrTempIIR g;
g.processOnFrame(frame,image);//this is the process i do on frame 
imshow("window",image);
waitKey(33);
}
}

Comment: thnx for help..
 i just new to stackoverflow

Comment: What is `GpyrTempIIR`?, if it is a custom type please also include its definition and implementations.

Comment: Also, are you sure your `VideoCapture` class is able to read the file..? Please run your code through a debugger and tell us after which line the error is occuring.

Comment: First thanks for fast response  
for 'GpyrTempIIR' is function i made to perform some future on frame of video file and i call it on the main 
and 'VideoCapture' is work good and i can run videos easy

Comment: what i want is to know what this error mean.

Comment: It is kinda hard to say what that error would mean if there aren't more details. Could you answer the questions posed by @Nabla and myself..? (PS - saying "it is a class I wrote..." is NOT the reply we are looking for)

Comment: i will edit the code and include this class

Comment: i try to include error as a snipped image but i can't it need at lest 10 reputation

Comment: You have just included the function; not the entire class.. There are variables like `first`, `LowPassHigh` and `LowPassLow` that haven't been initialized in your code. Just upload the image on the cloud and post the link here.

Comment: (http://imageshack.com/a/img713/5941/eobz.png)

Comment: and i already initialized this variables

Comment: `src.convertTo(src,CV_32F);` How does that even work? Source and destination are the same and they are both const references, too.